# LibGDX Gradlew no signing identity found matching

Tags: ios, xcode, gradle, libgdx, robovm

I'm currently trying to deploy my LibGDX application to ios using

```
./gradlew ios:createIPA
```

but I'm getting

```
> No Signing indentity found matching '*********'
```

In my build.gradle I've already got this setup:

```
robovm {
    iosSignIdentity="*********"
    iosProvisioningProfile = "**-**-**-**-**"
    iosSkipSigning = false
    stdoutFifo = null
    stderrFifo = null
}
```

I got my signing identity by entering this command:

```
192-225-162-91:project user120683$ security find-identity -v -p codesigning
1) ****** "Developer ID Application: Marcus D (*)"
2) ****** "iPhone Developer: Marcus D (*)"
3) ***** "iPhone Distribution: Marcus D (*)"
 3 valid identities found
```

and I copied my signing identity as the astricks before the "Iphone Developer" identity directly into my build.gradle but I'm still getting "no signing identity found ..."

The odd this was that this was working earlier today, I changed absolutely nothing and it just suddenly will not work. I'm bran new to development on apple, the LibGDX project was initially just for android but I decided that it was time to try ios. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I logged in this morning and I was able to redownload all of the certificates and it worked, I was able to create an IPA. Then I logged in later and it wouldn't work again even after redownloading all of the certificates. Very weird.